# R Function to convert character column in two data tables to numeric and maintain consistent numbering in each

Tags: r, function, parameters, data.table

This problem arises for me in a machine learning situation where there is an initial set of data (call it dtrain) and a subsequent set of similar data (call it dtest) where I wish to first factor a  column of class character and then convert to a numeric.  I want the string to factor to numeric mappings to be consistent in both data tables.  Since I will encounter dtrain first, I will see only a subset of the data.  When I encounter dtest, I will want to reuse the same levels and add new levels for the new unique strings.

A simple illustration:

```
dtrain <- data.table( colors = c('red','white','blue'))
dtest <- data.table( colors = c('green','white','red'))

factor(dtrain$colors)
[1] red   white blue 
Levels: blue red white

dtrain$colors <- as.numeric(factor(dtrain$colors))
dtrain$colors
[1] 2 3 1

color_levels <- c(c('blue','red','white'), c('green'))
dtest$colors <- as.numeric(factor(dtest$colors, color_levels))
dtest$colors
[1] 4 3 2
```

Here we see that white(3) and red(2) are consistent in both, and green(4) is found in dtest and not dtrain and so gets a level which comes after all the levels needed for dtrain$color.

I was able to write a function which will structure the levels appropriately given the two data tables and the target column.

```
ab.levels <- function( da, db, col_x ) {
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  ax <- sort(unique(eval(arguments$col_x, da)))
  bx <- unique(eval(arguments$col_x, db))
  return(c(ax, sort(setdiff(bx,ax))))
}

dtrain <- data.table( colors = c('red','white','blue'))
dtest <- data.table( colors = c('green','white','red'))

ab.levels( dtrain, dtest, colors)
[1] "blue"  "red"   "white" "green"
```

Now I would like a function which I can apply at will that will convert the columns to numerics and maintain the level order from the first table to the second.  Here is my naive code which utilizes ab.levels(), but doesn't work:

```
ab.char.to.numeric <- function (da, db, col_x)
{
  col_levels <- ab.levels( da, db, col_x)
  da$col_x <- as.numeric(factor(da$col_x, col_levels))
  db$col_x <- as.numeric(factor(db$col_x, col_levels))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `<-` on data.table columns, read about *update by reference* and `:=` operator.

There is probably easier way achieve it but at least it works - assuming I understand you correctly.
The `sk` stands for *surrogate key*.

```
library(data.table)
dtrain = data.table( colors = c('red','white','blue'))
dtest = data.table( colors = c('green','white','red'))

decode_to_sk = function(da, db, col_x){
    sk = unique(c(da[, unique(eval(as.name(col_x)))], db[, unique(eval(as.name(col_x)))]))
    lookup = setNames(seq_along(sk), sk)
    j.upd = call(":=", as.name(col_x), call("[", as.name("lookup"), as.name(col_x)))
    # j.upd builds call for `j` arg, here: colors := lookup[colors]
    da[, eval(j.upd)]
    db[, eval(j.upd)]
    return(TRUE)
}
print(dtrain)
#   colors
#1:    red
#2:  white
#3:   blue
print(dtest)
#   colors
#1:  green
#2:  white
#3:    red
decode_to_sk(dtrain, dtest, col_x = "colors")
#[1] TRUE
print(dtrain)
#   colors
#1:      1
#2:      2
#3:      3
print(dtest)
#   colors
#1:      4
#2:      2
#3:      1
```

If you want it to use on bigger project you want to check my R6 class called `IM` (stands for *Identity Management*) available as a part of [anchormodeling](https://github.com/jangorecki/anchormodeling) package.
Not sure but for large dataset it may be faster to use `lookup` as data.table instead of named vector, and do *update on join* instead current `colors := lookup[colors]`.

Comment: Is 'unique' guaranteed to preserve order as it seems?  If so, this meets all the requirements.  I don't really understand the intricacies of each of your steps necessary to make this all work as a function, but will chew on it some more.  Thanks.

Comment: About the `unique` yes it does, you can easily check it. The only tricky part is preparing unevaluated expression used in `j`, the twice `call`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your ab.char.to.numeric function will return only result of the last statement or explicitly specified return.  Here is how I would approach the solving this:

```
ab.char.to.numeric <- function (da, db, col_x)
{
    require(data.table)
    stopifnot(is.data.table(da))
    stopifnot(is.data.table(dt))

    data <- rbindlist(list(da, dt))
    data$col_x <- as.numeric(as.factor(data$col_x))
    da <- data[1:nrow(da)]
    db <- data[(nrow(da) + 1):.N]]

    return list(da, db)
}
```

or you can skip the function all together and just bind, transform and split

Comment: I should clarify that I'm not expecting anything returned.  My expectation is the side effect that col_x in data.tables da and db will be numeric after the call.

Comment: if you specify da and db as arguments to the function, they are treated within the context (name space) of that function. Meaning these are two different sets of variables - one in global space and one in the function one. You can mutate variables form the parent environment, by making your function search the calling/parent environment, but that is not recommended. If you insist, do not specify da & db in the function call.

Comment: I think that you should decompose `db <- data[(nrow(da) + 1):.N]]` for readers, please.

Comment: I am interested in the case where you train the model on the training data without the benefit of the test data.  The test data becomes available after it knows  'red','white', and 'blue', but not 'green'. The model will never see 'green' during training, It will only see 1,2,3 corresponding to 'blue','red','white'.  When dtest comes along it introduces 'green' ... green cannot be a 1, 2 or 3 because that is what the model learned for the other colors.  Green has to be some other number such as 4. In the above code it will be a '2' and conflict with 'red'.

Comment: data represents two data tables da and db stacked on top of each other. data.table `rbindlist` is extremely fast as compared to R's stock `rbind`. `db <- data[(nrow(da) + 1):.N]]` simply gets the bottom portion of the combined datta.table. `.N` returns number of rows in `data[]` -  the number of the last row. Hope this helps.